# Adding a line of code to all pages

Tags: theming

I have recently taken over the final stages of construction of 3 websites that were built in Drupal 7. I have never used drupal before and have run into a problem. My footer in one of the websites is not visible. This was due to the color style sheet not being pointed to in the page code. I copied the existing code into dreamweaver and resolved the issue, but cannot upload to the server as I cannot find the pages on the server, so i have no file i can replace.

The code looks like this:

@import url("themes/bartik/css/layoutb3ea.css?mry7g9");

@import url("themes/bartik/css/styleb3ea.css?mry7g9");

It needs to look tike this:

@import url("themes/bartik/css/layoutb3ea.css?mry7g9");

@import url("themes/bartik/css/styleb3ea.css?mry7g9");

@import url("sites/default/files/color/bartik-23dc1686/colors.css?m9ub8w");

You can see that the last line of code is missing.  I am used to working in dreamweaver and I am not familiar with the how the file system works in Drupal.

How do I add that line in to all the pages?

Comment: By looking at this, it seems that the site is using the Color module to alter the color on the site. I would just re-save the color settings first to see if that fixes. Files under sites/default/files is something created by Drupal - either an uploaded file, cached versions of CSS/JS, cropped images, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should familiarize yourself with Drupal theming. Check out the [Theming Guide](https://drupal.org/documentation/theme).

Basically, you want to edit the CSS in the theme that's currently being used on your site.

Answer (score 0):

@dcmouyard is right. Also you can find YOURTHEMENAME.info and edit it. Find `stylesheets[all][] = css/SOMECSS.css` and add your stylesheet with path.